# Nonhomogeneous linear transport equation solution via method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have been trying to figure out how to apply the method of characteristics to the non-homogeneous traffic equation. 
$$
u_t + u_x = sin(x), \\
u(x, 0) = e^{-x^2}
$$
I thought that forming the related system of ODEs and solving them would be sufficient:
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= 1, \\
\frac{du}{dt} &= \sin(x),
\end{align}
Solving for $x$ then for $u$, I get that $u(x, t) = \sin(x)t + e^{-(x-t)^2}$, which does not satisfy the original PDE.

I thought it could be due to the fact that the two ODEs are coupled, but not sure what the basis for such an argument would be.

What am I missing?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  initial curve is given 
$$x(r,0)=r $$
$$ t(r,0)=0$$
$$z(r,0)=e^{-r^2}$$
and the characteristic ODEs  are 
$$ \frac{dx}{ds}(r,s)=1$$
$$\frac{dt}{ds}(r,s)=1$$
$$\frac{dz}{ds}(r,s)= \sin x  $$
 we find
 $$ x(r,s)=s+\omega_1(r)$$
 $$t(r,s)=s+\omega_2(r)$$
 $$\frac{dz}{ds}(r,s)=\sin x$$
 Then 
 $$ x(r,s)=s+r$$
 $$t(r,s)=s$$
 $$ \frac{dz}{ds}(r,s)=\sin(r+s)$$
 therefore $z(r,s)=\int^s_0\sin(y+r)dy+\omega_3(r)$

we have $\omega_3(r)=z(r,0)=e{-r^2}$

then

$z(r,s)=\int^s_0\sin(y+r)dy+e^{-r^2}$

on the other hand

$$r(x,t)=x-t$$
$$s(x,t)=t$$
So
$$u(x,t)=e^{-(x-t)^2}+\int^t_0\sin(y+x-t)dy$$